# Running the same Rails app on localhost on different domains and on a different Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I want to run the same Rails 3 app at urls:  *davinci.local.dev:8081*   *davinci.testing.dev:8082* and with environments development and testing, respectively.

I am using Nginx and passenger. My first attempt was:

```
server {
      listen 8081;
      server_name .davinci.local.dev;
      root /Users/Nerian/NetBeansProjects/DaVinci/DaVinci/public;
      passenger_enabled on;
      rails_env development;   
      #rails_env development
   }

server {
      listen 8082;
      server_name .davinci.testing.dev;
      root /Users/Nerian/NetBeansProjects/DaVinci/DaVinci/public;
      passenger_enabled on;
      rails_env test;   
      #rails_env development
   }
```

Yet when I browse to said urls, I get to the same deployment. If I first request the testing one, then it is that the app that is served always, whether I browse to *davinci.local.dev* or *davinci.testing.dev*. If I first request the development one, then it is that one which is served always.

Both deployments are using the same root app. Is there a way to make this works?

The objective is to serve the same app at different ENV in different domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I wanted a Rails application (named apparat) to have two nginx instances: example.eu for english version of the site and example.ee for estonian version. They share exactly the same functionality, so it makes sense to have just one code base for it (but I do have to make sure static assets like user-uploaded images won't collide).

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.eu;
   root /home/apparat/public;
   passenger_enabled on;
   rails_env apparat_eng;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.ee;
   root /home/apparat/public;
   passenger_enabled on;
   rails_env apparat_ee;
}
```

However, similar to above, if I accessed example.ee, I got the example.eu instance of my Rails app. Possibly some quirk in nginx / passenger?

Anyway I got around by making an arbitrary symlink to /home/apparat, for instance

```
ln -s /home/apparat /home/apparat_eng
ln -s /home/apparat /home/apparat_ee
```

and changed the nginx config respectively

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.eu;
   root /home/apparat_eng/public;
   passenger_enabled on;
   rails_env apparat_eng;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.ee;
   root /home/apparat_ee/public;
   passenger_enabled on;
   rails_env apparat_ee;
}
```

So I'm able to trick nginx into thinking these are different directories.

Comment: This is kind of an 'aside' but are you also using nginx to do your logging. I can log my GET requests just fine, but I'm having trouble logging the body response from POST requests. Just thought you might have some insight.

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach. The development server is served by nginx using passenger while the testing server is started on demand when using rake spec:acceptance.

So nginx.conf is:

```
server {
  listen 8081;
  server_name .davinci.local.dev;
  root /Users/Nerian/NetBeansProjects/DaVinci/DaVinci/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env development;   
  #rails_env development
}
```

Just that.

And in spec/support/custom_env.rb

```
Capybara.run_server = true
Capybara.app_host = 'http://davinci.testing.dev:8082'
Capybara.server_port = 8082
```

And that's the magic.

Comment: This is kind of an 'aside' but are you also using nginx to do your logging. I can log my GET requests just fine, but I'm having trouble logging the body response from POST requests. Just thought you might have some insight.